# Why can a process launched with `unshare -m` affect the mounts in the host?

Tags: linux, namespaces, mount

Here is what I did:

```
$ sudo unshare -m --propagation unchanged sh    # Run a shell with `unshare` in a separate mount namespace
# cd /tmp
# mkdir foo bar
# mount --bind foo bar  # This mount is supposed to be only visible in this separate mount namespace, right?
# exit                  # Back to the original shell
$ cat /proc/self/mountinfo | grep foo     # Why can I see it here???
272 26 8:1 /tmp/foo /tmp/bar rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda1 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

I know it will work as expected when I run `sudo unshare -m sh`, but that is because by default `unshare` will recursively set all mount's propagation as private (see code [here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/v2.33/sys-utils/unshare.c#L50) and [here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/v2.33/sys-utils/unshare.c#L153:L160)). When I run it with the `--propagation unchanged`, `unshare` will not set mount's propagation at all and it will only call the `unshare()` syscall with `CLONE_NEWNS` in which case the the mount made by the launched shell will be visible in host mount namespace as you see in the above example.

So my question is, since it is mount propagation to isolate the mount/umount operations, then why do we need `CLONE_NEWNS` at all? Or `CLONE_NEWNS` is only used to isolate setting mount propagation (rather than mount/umount operations) for different mount namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Mount propagation type determines whether new mounts and unmounts of mount points under the mount point are propagated back to parent namespace. By default all the mounts points are marked as shared mounts. If you create a new namespace and leave the propagation type unchanged, then new mounts under these mounts will be propagated back to the parent. But if there is a private mount point in the parent namespace, then the mount point itself is copied to the new namespace but new mounts are not propagated back to the parent.

Lets make an example:

```
# mkdir -p /tmp/shared-mount
# mount --bind --make-shared /tmp/shared-mount /tmp/shared-mount

# mkdir -p /tmp/private-mount
# mount --bind --make-private /tmp/private-mount /tmp/private-mount

# grep "/tmp" /proc/self/mountinfo
406 29 8:5 /tmp/shared-mount /tmp/shared-mount rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
420 29 8:5 /tmp/private-mount /tmp/private-mount rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

Note the "shared:1", indicating a shared mount point. Now:

```
# unshare -m --propagation unchanged /bin/bash
# grep "/tmp" /proc/self/mountinfo
551 432 8:5 /tmp/shared-mount /tmp/shared-mount rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
552 432 8:5 /tmp/private-mount /tmp/private-mount rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

All good. Now lets create a submounts under these mount points in the new namespace:

```
# mkdir -p /tmp/shared-mount/submount
# mount --bind /tmp/shared-mount/submount /tmp/shared-mount/submount

# mkdir -p /tmp/private-mount/submount
# mount --bind /tmp/private-mount/submount /tmp/private-mount/submount

# grep "/tmp" /proc/self/mountinfo
551 432 8:5 /tmp/shared-mount /tmp/shared-mount rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
552 432 8:5 /tmp/private-mount /tmp/private-mount rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
553 551 8:5 /tmp/shared-mount/submount /tmp/shared-mount/submount rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
555 432 8:5 /tmp/shared-mount/submount /tmp/shared-mount/submount rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
577 552 8:5 /tmp/private-mount/submount /tmp/private-mount/submount rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

You can now observe the `/proc/self/mountinfo` from another shell under the parent namespace and see, that the new submount under the private mount point has not propagated. Or exit the new namespace, like you did:

```
# exit
# grep "/tmp" /proc/self/mountinfo
406 29 8:5 /tmp/shared-mount /tmp/shared-mount rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
420 29 8:5 /tmp/private-mount /tmp/private-mount rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
556 406 8:5 /tmp/shared-mount/submount /tmp/shared-mount/submount rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
554 29 8:5 /tmp/shared-mount/submount /tmp/shared-mount/submount rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda5 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

Under the new namespace, you can also make shared mount point private:

```
# mount --make-private /tmp/shared-mount
```

In real life, it is even more complicated than that. Good additional reading:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html (about mountinfo)

Comment: I understand what you said. But my question is, what is `CLONE_NEWNS` is for? In http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html, it is clearly mentioned that when a process creates a new mount namespace with the CLONE_NEWNS flag, subsequent modifications to the mount point list in either mount namespace will NOT (by default) affect the mount point list seen in the other namespace. But that is not what we see in my test and your test, it is `--make-private` or `--make-slave` to isolate the mount/umount operations between mount namespaces instead of `CLONE_NEWNS`.

Comment: And they are not shared by kernel by default. But systemd creates shared mount points and if you leave them unchanged when creating a new namespace, then this default does not apply here. And CLONE_NEWNS still creates a new mount namespace, even if it is all shared at the beginning.

Comment: So what is actually isolated `CLONE_NEWNS`? What is its actual effect?

Comment: Mount points are isolated. Look at the mount ID-s (first number in /proc/self/mountpoints). They are different. You can make a mount point private in one namespace and it stays shared in the other.

Comment: Yes, I agree! So `CLONE_NEWNS` is NOT used to isolate mount propagations between mount namespaces which is actually controlled by the propagation attribute of the mounts, instead with `CLONE_NEWNS` setting mount's propagation attribute is isolated between mount namespaces, i.e., changing a mount's propagation attribute (e.g., change a shared mount to a private mount) in one mount namespace will not be propagated to any other mount namespaces.